# Cakephp Countercache issue

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

Hi i am using Countercache  in 2.0 i need to add some condition as follows.
But it is not working.. Its incrementing the field if 'counterCache' => true, It not consider the condition i added.

**Post hasMany WallPost**

**WallPost belongs to Post**

```
    public $belongsTo = array(
    'WallPost' => array(
        'className' => 'WallPost',
        'foreignKey' => 'wallpost_id',
         'counterScope' =>array(
             'WallPost.post_id' =>3,
         ),
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'counterCache' => true
    ),
```

Comment: I've checked cakephp documentation In 1.3 I've found about counter cache, And its correct as per 1.3, but in 2.0 I'm unable to find any topic related to counter cache.

Comment: Looks fine according the the 2.0 book as well:  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

Comment: yes I went through Cookbook but could not find any solution :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
'WallPost' => array(
    'className' => 'WallPost',
    'foreignKey' => 'wallpost_id',
    'fields' => '',
    'order' => '',
    'counterCache' => array('WallPost.post_id' =>3)
),
```

You are right though the documentation is confusing on this.